# Passing Argument to NSInvocationOperation via NSInvocation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am in the process of familiarizing myself more with NSOperation concurrency and I came across an issue with `NSInvocationOperation`.

Here's the method I'd like to run:

```
- (void) myTaskMethod:(NSString *)stringArg {
    NSLog(@"StringArg: %@", stringArg);
}
```

And here's how I invoke it  **** working ****

```
NSInvocationOperation * invocationOperation2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myTaskMethod:) object:@"HELLO WORLD!"];
invocationOperation2.completionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"We Finished w/ NSInvocationOperation");
};
[invocationOperation2 start];
```

#### Question

I'm trying to do this a different way by preparing an NSInvocation and passing it that way.  Here's my code:

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(myTaskMethod:)];
NSInvocation * myTaskMethodInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
NSString * hello = @"Hello From NSInvocation";
[myTaskMethodInvocation setArgument:&hello atIndex:2];
NSInvocationOperation * invocationOperation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithInvocation:myTaskMethodInvocation];
invocationOperation1.completionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"We finished w/ NSInvocation");
};
[invocationOperation1 start];
```

It is logging "We finished w/ NSInvocation" however, `myTaskMethod:` never runs.  I imagine I'm missing something so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `invocationWithMethodSignature`:

> The new object must have its selector set with `setSelector:` and its
>   arguments set with `setArgument:atIndex:` before it can be invoked.

I think you need to add:

```
[myTaskMethodInvocation setTarget:self];
[myTaskMethodInvocation setSelector:@selector(myTaskMethod:)];
```

Comment: That did it.  I guess I assumed it would get that information from the methodSignature.  Will accept in 6 minutes (when it lets me), thank you.  Do you know why it even bothers trying to take a methodSignature?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think `NSInvocation` needs to know some implementation details about the method in order to call it, which are encapsulated in the `NSMethodSignature` object. If you look at the docs for it talks about stack frame length and return types and such...